# Use new SQL table for each "conversation" in db

Tags: php, sql, database, web-applications

I have this web application I'm developing for my major project, one of it features is messaging between registered users. The whole messaging system is created that every time when message is sent, new record in table conversations is created and new table in second database is created, table name is made from id of both users and conversation id. In this table whole conversation between two ppl is stored.

My question is, is this good approach or creating tables at my database on daily basis would be to much for server to handle?

Comment: Keep one table and contain all your chat logs inside there. Do not create multiple tables for different chats. It will be extremely hard to monitor/moderate

Comment: Isn't that going to make whole chat experience to slow, to search always for past messages in one table full of messages?

Comment: "is this good approach" No. You'll thank yourself in the future if you use what @DarylGill suggested...

Comment: @JakubZak worry about performance onny when you have to. Also, you have quite powerful tools for this scenario: partitioning used with indexes on RDBMSs, or proper sharding and indexes, if you use approaches like mongoDB... How many rows will you have? A couple of tens of millions of rows are even handled easily without partitioning with some appropriate hardware beneath...

Comment: @JakubZak No, it wont make things slow. Depending on your queries you perform. Think of it like this, think of the databases that Facebook controls, do you think there is a new table for every new private message group?  How hard do you think that would be to moderate considering all the users on the site?    All you will have to do is perform your queries to look for two specific user names and return the results.

Comment: The solution to slow lookups is to [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) the messages table. You needn't split the data out until the data size gets *enormous*.

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mer Mortals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating new tables based on request is never a good idea. You could create a table which connects user_ids to a conversation:

```
conversations:
id : 2348
started_at: 2013-03-28 17:13:00

user_conversations:
id        : 538
conversation_id: 2348
message   : "Hey Jakub, how are you?"
user_id   : 5831
posted_at : 2013-03-28 17:14:50

id        : 539
conversation_id: 2348
message   : "Hey Anyone, I'm fine, how are you?"
user_id   : 95234
posted_at : 2013-03-28 17:15:30
```

etc.

id: PK, key on user_id

You might want to play around with keys tho, but this is a nice setup for this. You will connect messages to a user and a coversation. This way a conversation is not limited to 2 users either.

Comment: Possibly roughly explain database relations, the OP seems newish  to this whole design concept

Comment: that is not an explination on why you would use a foreign key with relationships... To the OP, referneces: http://www.functionx.com/sql/Lesson11.htm    and   http://databases.about.com/cs/administration/g/primarykey.htm    -- Both links I have found useful in the past

Comment: OP did not ask questions regarding relationships between tables nor gave any info he does or does not know about it. I'm simply answering his question.